# Android Studio: Database search functions fine but unable to display all records via button

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio, mobile

Much like the title says. I have followed my class tutorials but chunks seem to be missing and it gets a bit confusing flicking between video lectures and pdf's when you're not too well versed in such.

When the app is executed the user can search for a song by year, or display all records within the database. However, originally all records would display from clicking the search by year button instead of the display all button. The search function works as intended but the display all button I cannot seem to figure out, despite following my lecturer's tutorials.

The first section of code is "MainActivity.java" and the second is "OpenDatabse.java"

```
package com.example.dbcopyexample1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static String DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME;
    private static String CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER;

    //private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "music.db";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MUSIC_DB";

    Context ctx;

    OpenDatabase sqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb;

    // Control Objects
    EditText searchByYearEditText;
    Button searchButton;
    TextView numRecordTextView;
    Button displayAllRecordsButton;
    TextView resultsTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupDatabaseStrings();
        setUpDatabase();

        InitDataBase(); // open the music.db for reading and writing

        //sqh.DisplayRecords( sqdb ); // Display the songtable records to the run window

        setupControls();

        numRecordTextView.setText( Integer.toString( sqh.numberOfRecordsInSongtable( sqdb ) ) );

    } //  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    protected void setupControls()
    {
        searchByYearEditText = findViewById(R.id.searchByYearEditText);

        searchButton = findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                resultsTextView.setText( sqh.searchByYearInSongtable( sqdb,
                        searchByYearEditText.getText().toString()) );


            }
        });

        numRecordTextView = findViewById(R.id.numRecordTextView);

        displayAllRecordsButton = findViewById(R.id.displayAllRecordsButton);

        displayAllRecordsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });

        resultsTextView = findViewById(R.id.resultsTextView);

    } // protected void setupControls()

    protected void setupDatabaseStrings()
    {
        // Full path to where we will copy music.db to on the emulator!
        DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                "/databases/" + OpenDatabase.DATABASE_NAME;

        // Used to check if the "databases" folder exists
        CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                "/databases";

        // Debug information
        Log.i("DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME","DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME = " + DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME);
        Log.i("CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER","CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER = " + CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER);

    } // protected void setupDatabaseStrings()

    protected void setUpDatabase()
    {
        ctx = this.getBaseContext();
        Log.w("CTX","ctx = " + ctx);
        Log.w("getBaseContext()","getBaseContext = " + getBaseContext());
        try
        {
            CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // protected void setUpDatabase()

    protected void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException
    {
        Log.w( LOG_TAG , "Starting copying...");

        String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH_AND_NAME;

        File databaseFolder = new File( CHECK_DATABASES_FOLDER );

        // databases folder exists ? No - Create it and copy !!!
        if ( !databaseFolder.exists() )
        {
            databaseFolder.mkdir();

            // Open the sqlite database "music.db" found in the assets folder
            InputStream in = ctx.getAssets().open(OpenDatabase.DATABASE_NAME);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;

            while ( (length = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )
            {
                out.write(buffer,0,length);

            } // while ( (length = in.read(buffer)) > 0 )

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Completed.");

        } // if ( !databaseFolder.exists() )

    } // protected void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException

    public void InitDataBase()
    {
        // Init the SQLite Helper Class
        sqh = new OpenDatabase(this);

        // RETRIEVE A READABLE AND WRITEABLE DATABASE
        sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();

    } // public void InitDataBase()

    public void DisplayRecords()
    {
        Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songtable", null);
        if (c != null)
        {
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String id = c.getString(0);

                    String songtitle = c.getString(1);

                    String year = c.getString(2);

                    String artist = c.getString(3);

                    String album = c.getString(4);

                    Log.w("SONG_TABLE", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + songtitle);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c.close();

    } // public void DisplayRecords()


} // public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

```
package com.example.dbcopyexample1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class OpenDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "music.db";

    // TOGGLE THIS NUMBER FOR UPDATING TABLES AND DATABASE
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    OpenDatabase(Context context)
    {
        super( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION );

    } // OpenDatabase(Context context)

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

    } // public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {

    } // public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

    public String searchByYearInSongtable(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String searchYear)
    {
        String result = "";

        Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songtable where year = '" + searchYear + "'",
                null);

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String id = c.getString(0);
                    result = result + id + ",";

                    String songtitle = c.getString(1);
                    result = result + songtitle + ",";

                    String year = c.getString(2);
                    result = result + year + ",";

                    String artist = c.getString(3);
                    result = result + artist + ",";

                    String album = c.getString(4);
                    result = result + album + "\n"; // new line control character

                    Log.w("SONG_TABLE", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + songtitle);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else
            {
                result = "No Records Found for the Search Year = " + searchYear;
            }
        }
        c.close();

        return result;

    } // public String allRecordsInSongtable(SQLiteDatabase sqdb)

    public int numberOfRecordsInSongtable(SQLiteDatabase sqdb)
    {
        int count = 0;

        Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM songtable", null);

        if (c != null)

        {
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String id = c.getString(0);

                    count = Integer.parseInt( id );

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c.close();
        return count;
    } // public int numberOfRecordsInSongtable(SQLiteDatabase sqdb)

} // public class OpenDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not called your **DisplayRecords()** function to display records on tap of **displayAllRecordsButton**.

```
displayAllRecordsButton = findViewById(R.id.displayAllRecordsButton);

displayAllRecordsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        DisplayRecords();
    }
});
```

Also, in the DisplayRecords() method, you need to set text to the text view.
Below is your code I edited to display records.

```
public void DisplayRecords()
{
    String result = "";
    Cursor c = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songtable", null);
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String id = c.getString(0);

                String songtitle = c.getString(1);

                String year = c.getString(2);

                String artist = c.getString(3);

                String album = c.getString(4);

                Log.w("SONG_TABLE", "ID = " + id + " Songtitle = " + songtitle);
                
                result = result + "ID = " + id + "Song Title = " + songtitle + "Artist = " + artist + "Album = " + album + "Year = " + year + "\n";

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c.close();

    resultsTextView.setText(result);

} // public void DisplayRecords()
```